# In Visual Studio 2008, how can I add a 'using blah.myblah;' to all new page codebehinds?

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way to modify the default template for new pages so that it includes my custom 'using' statements?

Answer (score 1):

From [Steve's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/steve/archive/2007/04/10/changing-the-default-using-directives-in-visual-studio.aspx), it suggests that you edit the Class.cs file located in:

```
%Program Files%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class.zip
```

Be sure to regenerate the template cache by running:

```
%Program Files%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe /setup
```

Make sure you wait for the process to exit (watch your task manager!).

Web templates are in a different zip:

```
%Program Files%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\1033\WebForm.zip
```